# How to select one by one the element in web scraping using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want only h3[0] and h6[1], for example.

```
<div class="span16">
    <h3>Shroot, Stephanie</h3>
    <h6>Chemistry</h6>
    <h6>December 2021</h6>
    <p>Thesis or dissertation
    <h3>Shroot</h3>
```

i use BeautifulSoup, and for loop to get information

```
url = line.strip() 
r_html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
r_html_sc = requests.get(url, headers=headers).status_code 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, "html.parser") 
thesis_infos = soup.find('div',{"class":"span16"}) 
if thesis_infos is not None: 
thesis_infos_text = thesis_infos.text.strip() 
else: thesis_infos_1 = " " 
print(thesis_infos_text) 
thesis_infos_lines = thesis_infos_text.readlines() 
author1_1 = thesis_infos_lines[0] 
year1_1 = thesis_infos_lines[2]
```

Comment: And you're using which package or API? You using `BeautifulSoup` by any chance? In general, don't just post an open question, but also post your attempt to solve it. This way we can help you with the tools you declare to be using.

Comment: yes, I use BeautifulSoup, but, in this HTML there is no class to select the element

Comment: url = line.strip()
        r_html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text 
        # r_html_sc = requests.get(url, headers=headers).status_code 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, "html.parser")
        thesis_infos = soup.find('div',{"class":"span16"})
        if thesis_infos is not None:
            thesis_infos_text = thesis_infos.text.strip()
        else:
            thesis_infos_1 = " "
        print(thesis_infos_text)
        thesis_infos_lines = thesis_infos_text.readlines()
        author1_1 = thesis_infos_lines[0]
        year1_1 = thesis_infos_lines[2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
The easiest way is probably to use BeautifulSoup, like so:

```
soup.find_all("h3")[0]
soup.find_all("h6")[1]
```

Here is a short example, filtering for links on google.com:

```
import requests as requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a")
print(links[0])
```

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import re

code = """
<div class="span16">
    <h3>Shroot, Stephanie</h3>
    <h6>Chemistry</h6>
    <h6>December 2021</h6>
    <p>Thesis or dissertation
    <h3>Shroot</h3>
"""

h3_matches = re.findall(".*<h3>(.+)<\\/h3>", code)
h6_matches = re.findall(".*<h6>(.+)<\\/h6>", code)
print(h3_matches[0])
print(h6_matches[1])
```

output:

```
Shroot, Stephanie
December 2021
```

Comment: thanks, yes that what i want but: code is = soup.find('div',{"class":"span16"}) #?

Comment: it gives : TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Could you post the entire error message?

Comment: what is: code =

Comment: thesis_infos = soup.find('div',{"class":"span16"})
        code = str(thesis_infos)
        h3_matches = re.findall(".*<h3>(.+)<\\/h3>", code)
        h6_matches = re.findall(".*<h6>(.+)<\\/h6>", code)
        print(h3_matches[0])
        print(h6_matches[1])

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. You should replace code with r_html. But I advise to just use soup.find_all() instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
    thesis_infos = soup.find('div',{"class":"span16"})
    code = str(thesis_infos)
    h3_matches = re.findall(".*<h3>(.+)<\\/h3>", code)
    h6_matches = re.findall(".*<h6>(.+)<\\/h6>", code)
    print(h3_matches[0])
    print(h6_matches[1])
```